# Configuration cache state could not be cached: field 'actions' from type 'org.gradle.api.DefaultTask': error writing value of type 'java.util.Arra

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Installed Android studio giraffe with latest flutter and dart. I am getting web app running but only android app i  am getting this error.

[Gradle: "Configuration cache state could not be cached"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71793217/gradle-configuration-cache-state-could-not-be-cached)

I have tried the above answers but no use. Just installed Android Studio Giraffe and latest flutter and dart. I have been trying for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it after 3 days of work.
Upgraded gradle from 7.5.0 to 8.1.1
[kotlin version  ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0']

gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1.1-all.zip

build.gradle
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'